# How do I redirect STDOUT to .json for logs in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, winston, log4js-node

I need to have my logs in `.json` format and currently I use [express-js](https://github.com/expressjs/express) server and my logs looks the following:

```
Error: Cannot return null for non-nullable field Query.get_bar.
Error: Cannot return null for non-nullable field Query.get_bar.
Error: Cannot return null for non-nullable field Query.get_foo.
```

I figured out there're some logger frameworks (log4js, winstonjs) but I don't want to log manually (i.e., `console.log(123)`), I'm interested in redirecting my STDOUT, converting it to JSON and writing to some `.log` file.

What's the most simple solution for this task?

Update: there's a [related](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/1468) issue on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

The `process.stdout` and `process.stderr` pipes are independent of whatever actual code you're running using Node, so if you want their output sent to files, then make your main entry point script capture stdout/stderr output and that's simply what it'll do for as long as Node.js runs that script.

You can add log writing yourself by tapping into `` process.stdout.on(`data`, data => ...) `` (and stderr equivalent), or you can [pipe their output](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options) to a file, or (because why reinvent the wheel?) you can find a logging solution that does that for you, but then *that's on you* to find, asking others to recommend you one is [off topic](/help/on-topic) on Stackoverflow.

Also note that stdout/stderr have some sync/async quirks, so give https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_a_note_on_process_i_o a read because that has important information for you to be aware of.

Answer (score -2):

The [example](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#usage) from winston basically solved the issue.